# c# steam64 ID to steam32 ID

Tags: c#, steam

вопрос таков:
Как конвертировать steam64 ID в steam32 ID?
Ну или может где-то на копме лежит файл стима где можно узнать SteamID 32?
Или можно написать конвертер на другом языке, только чтоб его можно было портировать в WPF C# и желательно с гайдом как его портировать )

Примеры:
**steam64 ID** - 76561198192371814
конвертировать в
**steam32 ID** - U:1:232106086

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**id3 - то что нужно**

**steam32 ID - такой чтоб совпадал как Steam/userdata/...**

Пробовал библиотеку steamkit2, но там нужно входить в аккаунт чтобы получить steam32 ID.
Пробовал SteamUserInfo, там можно получить всю информацию о некоторых аккаунтах, о каких точно я так и не понял. У меня аккаунтов около 200, библиотека показывает же только 9.

Облазил кучу сайтов, но там почему-то большинство это как 32 в 64 конвертировать.

И так. Можно как-то составить код чтобы можно было конвертировать id? Могу ответить на вопросы которые вы зададите.

---

Возможно это может помочь - https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID

Comment: `большинство это как 64 в 3` вам вроде это и надо

Comment: @aepot Ммм, мне в основном сайты как сделать на PHP попадались. И в основном на c# только 3 в 64

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, что на самом деле надо. Отредактируйте вопрос. Перечитайте его хотя-бы.

Comment: Ну так, все же правильно? Нет? (Понял, извиняюсь. Я просто с 12 утра сижу, ломаю голову разными задачами. На этой остановился...)

Comment: По вашей же ссылке показано, что к чему. В чем именно проблема? Примитивная двоичная арифметика.

Comment: Я не шарю вообще в этих примерах. Я устал, прошу помочь. Сам не могу понять

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31271799/12888024 вот почти готовый код

Comment: Слушай, я видимо не понимаю чего-то. PHP - это что за язык? Или я просто не правильно прочитал содержание на том вопросе который вы скинули?

Comment: Там же человек английским по белому пишет, что это псевдокод, а не PHP, а PHP - нормальный язык. В рамках вашей задачи почти любой язык будет выглядеть одинаково.

Comment: Псевдокод? Что это? И там по моему не совсем тот id3 который мне нужен

Comment: Судя по вашей же ссылке именно тот

Comment: **steamid3 - такой чтоб совпадал как Steam/userdata/...** У вас есть стим? Посмотрите, а то я не знаю как иначе тот формат может называться

Comment: Нету, я не играю в игры. С мобилы неудобно писать код, так бы уже написал, там пара минут. Но что вас останавливает от того чтобы скопировать и попробовать то что я дал выше? Тупо усталость? Попробуйте Ctrl+C потом Ctrl+V, потом поправить ошибки и готово. Но судя по тому что я вижу даже править ничего не придется.

Comment: Опять же, это не совсем тот id3 который мне нужен. Я привел пример в основной части.

Comment: Смотрим в вашу же ссылку и в табличке видим, что **STEAM_1** это **U**. Я в вас верю.

Comment: Я картинку прикрепил.    

Вывод с вашего ответа: STEAM_0:0:116053043   

Мне же нужно: U:1:232106086

Comment: 116053043 * 2 внезапно = 232106086

Comment: Да ладно? Реально, секунду проверю... (И правда, только... Незнаю так ли должно быть, но на некоторых аккаунтах значение колеблется +-1 единицу)

Comment: Вам ответ уже ниже дали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вообще не понимаю, что я творю, но, судя вот по этой ссылке https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID

> Another commonly used representation, referred to as a "Steam3 ID," is represented as: "[letter:1:W]". Many games will use this format for player SteamIDs (e.g., [U:1:1234]) when printed from a status command for example.

> W=Z*2+Y

можно получить следующее

```
string ConvertToSteam3(long steamId)
{
    long acc = steamId >> 1 & 0b11111111111111111111111111111L;
    long y = steamId & 0b1;
    return $"U:1:{acc*2+y}";
}
```

Альтернативная, более короткая версия

```
string ConvertToSteam3(long steamId) => $"U:1:{steamId & 0x1FFFFFFF}";
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToSteam3(76561198192371814));
```

Вывод

```
U:1:232106086
```

ЗЫ: я так понял, буковку U надо подбирать ещё в зависимости о типа аккаунта.

Comment: В комментах всё есть, даже ссылка на готовый код, я просто с мобилы

Comment: сорян, я начал писать код ещё до комментов и не читал их. Ну не выкидывать теперь жеж =)

Comment: Да всё верно получилось, просто U тоже вычисляется из лонга и маппится из таблички в доке

Comment: Буковка U мне не нужна, мне нужно как в userdata, то есть: 232106086. И ваш код не точно выводит id.

Comment: @gnomuk что значит "не точно"?

Comment: А, ну... Что происходит сегодня. Да ладно... И на это я потратил весь день. 
Спасибо вам обоим, реально. Чтобы я без вас делал. Желаю удачи и счастья!

Comment: @gnomuk на здоровье!

Comment: @gnomuk вот версия покороче `string ConvertToSteam3(long steamId) => $"U:1:{steamId & 0x1FFFFFFF}";`, я добрался до компа

Comment: @aepot ‍♂️ то то я гляжу, что там то двиг, то на 2 умножение

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, спокойной ночи, если вы в +3 живете :)

Comment: Слушай, некоторые аккаунты он нормально проходит, а с некоторыми конкретно не угадывает, прям совсем.

Comment: И еще, что забавно. У меня в одном проекте, в тестовом, все замечательно. А в своей панели будущей не тот ID выдает. Это очень странно, на одном аккаунте выдает неверное значение в обоих проектах, а на другом аккаунте выдает верное значение только в 1 проекте. Твоя сокращенная версия выдает другой результат, вот в чем прикол

Comment: И все же обе выдают неверный результат для 1 аккаунта. Сможешь решить как-то? А то я точно знаю что для меня это точно не возможно

Comment: @gnomuk аккаунт и его требуемое значение в студию. А то так как я пойму что там не работает

Comment: Вот id64 - 76561199256632399;
Требуемый результат - 1296366671

Примерный выходной результат твоего кода 222 тысячи что-там.. В общем не верный, но для некоторых аккаунтов подходит, почему-то.. Ну или может где-то на копме лежит файл стима где можно узнать SteamID 32?

Comment: Я сейчас заплачу... Из в 64ID нужно вычесть это - 76561197960265728

Типо: 76561199256632399 - 76561197960265728 = 1296366671. То что нужно.